# How to pass a parameter to a class between different modules' same classes in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, abstract-class

I have 5 modules and all modules includes same classes, but all classes' content have different codes in to the run method.

```
mainpackage
    |  \ moduleA
    |       \ LoginClass
    |            + run(hashMapContext)
    |       \ LogOutClass
    |             + run(hashMapContext)
    |       \ GetInfoClass
    |             + run(hashMapContext)
    |
    |  \ moduleB
    |       \ LoginClass
    |             + run(hashMapContext)
    |       \ LogOutClass
    |             + run(hashMapContext)
    |       \ GetInfoClass
    |             + run(hashMapContext)
```

I have a field `(moduleType)` and i am trying to this

```
moduleType = moduleA

getInfo.run(hashMapContext)
```

How to develop this code? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcVEI.jpg)

here is answer thanks to @Jhon D.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ICommon obj = newInstance("a");
        obj.run("expect A");

    }


    public static ICommon newInstance(String type) {

        switch (type) {
            case "a":
                return new ModuleALogin();
            case "b":
                return new ModuleBLogin();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should make use of abstract classes...

Comment: I think, You should start with redesign, You should create a jar having all the classes which is common among Modules. Include it in classpath of Modules

Comment: `getInfo.run()` Where do this method comes from ? And I don't see the relation between `moduleType = moduleA` and `getInfo.run(hashMapContext)`
Besides, what do you mean by module ?

Comment: Do you have LoginClass in different packages in moduleA & B.. right (which is basic..)  ? .

Comment: There is no anything, i am just plannig and thinking how can i do. @davidxxx

Comment: @javaguy yes you are right, but I should build something like that so that I can work with a parameter

Comment: So, what is your need ?

Comment: an example or an idea. by the way i am new in java. sory for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use common interface that contains method: `run(hashMapContext)`.

Ok, if you want example. It could be similar to:

```
public void foo() {
    // ...
    CommonInterface obj = newInstance(module);
    obj.run(hashMapContext);
    // ...
}

public CommonInterface newInstance(module) {
    switch (module) {
        case A:
            return ClassFromModuleA;
        case B:
            return ClassFromModuleB;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought it but how can i pass parameter to correct module? is there a code sample?